# Selenium, find element by <td>

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, automation

I'm pretty new to test automation and right now I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to find an element by `<td>` text , in my case `"Man pdr"`. I will attach a picture. Basically my goal is to click this element, by `<td>` text, not by class because there are lots of classes with the same name. I don't really want to use direct `xpath` in order to make it more dynamic (to find it even if it changes locations). Is there any way to do it? I'm using `Selenium` + `Java`.
[image]

Code:

```
login.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='outlet30all‌​']/table/tbody/tr[co‌​ntains(text(), 'Man pdr')]"));
```

Comment: Right now i'm trying something like this , but that doesn't work. login.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='outlet30all']/table/tbody/tr[contains(text(), 'Man pdr')]"));

Comment: have you tried adding "tr" after "td" like "//*[@id='outlet30all‌​']/table/tbody/tr/td[co‌​ntains(text(), 'Man pdr')]"?

Comment: @Kushal Yes, doesn't work though. Andresson's solution works. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid including `tbody` tag in your `XPath`. Try below code:

```
login.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Man pdr']"));
```

Comment: R.R, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)